# How can I change my INNER JOIN to an OUTER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, nullable

I have 2 tables : `Users` and `Documents`.

1 User can have 0 or several documents.

I would like to display each user and their documents, but the problem : I would like to display users that have no documents, in a result like this (assume `IdUser`s 3 and 5 have no documents):

```
IdUser IdDocument DocumentName
====== ========== ============
1      1          test11.pdf
1      2          test12.pdf
1      3          test13.pdf
2      4          test21.pdf
2      5          test21.pdf
3      NULL       NULL
4      6          test41.pdf
5      NULL       NULL
```

Comment: So you need a `LEFT JOIN`, not `INNER`.

Comment: Its always better to just ask a question on SO instead of actually learning even the most **VERY BASIC** things about the language or systems you are trying to use.  `JOIN`s are very complicated and advanced and not something you should try to investigate in your own.

Comment: Whoever upvoted this should have their head examined and voting privileges revoked.

Comment: [Here's a canonical answer for you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use a `LEFT JOIN` to perform this operation.

```
create table users
(
  userid int
)

create table documents
(
  documentid int,
  userid int,
  documentname varchar(10)
)

insert into users values (1)
insert into users values (2)
insert into users values (3)
insert into users values (4)

insert into documents values (1, 1, 'test')
insert into documents values (2, 1, 'test 1')
insert into documents values (3, 2, 'test 2')
insert into documents values (3, 3, 'test 3')

select *
from users u
left join documents d
on u.userid = d.userid
```

see a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e56b/1) for a test

You should do some research on `JOINs`, here is a good description of the `JOINs`:

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: While you're right, I'm hesitant to +1 because the signs clearly state "don't feed the fish." :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I only answered because we all have to start somewhere with SQL. Maybe they truly didn't know where to start.

Comment: @bluefeet - This could easily have been answered by any of the most basic tutorials/intros to SQL.  It's beyond a waste of time and space to have it here on SO.  There's already a canonical answer about `JOIN` types, this is basically just noise.  I won't -1 because of the effort you put in, but seriously, don't feed the fish.

Comment: I was half-kidding. But JNK's link was a good one. A bing/google search would have probably yielded it also.

Comment: @JNK point taken, I will keep it in mind for future.  I guess I was feeling overly generous this morning.